# Multiplication algorithm up to 4 numbers to get the result of array results

Tags: java, algorithm

```
this is my numbers in an array int [] ids {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
this is my  an int [] result = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,24,27,28,30,32,35,36,40,42,45,48,49,54,56,63,64,63,72,81};
```

I build the matrix 4/4 with random numbers, randomly selected from an array of ids.

```
5,2,3,7 
3,2,3,9 
7,3,3,4 
4,5,3,2
```

Of these numbers in the matrix I want to arrange multiplication results.

I use max 4 numbers of the matrix to do that. 
I can not allow that, I will pick the matrix of numbers which I will not be able to arrange a result from array result .

eg. I draw the result array number with a value of 1, and the matrix does not have any numbers with a value of 1.

How to prevent from that I will draw the matrix of numbers which I will not be able to arrange a result of the result array?

```
                private int[] ids = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
                private int total =1;
                private static final int  a=7;
                private static final int  b=7;
                    Random rand = new Random();
    int tablica[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,24,27,28,30,32,35,36,40,42,45,48,49,54,56,63,64,63,72,81};
    int i = tablica[rand.nextInt(36)];


    private void createLayoutDynamically() {

    won = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.won);
    for ( int qq = 1; qq < a; qq++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

        won.addView(tableRow);

    for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {

        myButton = new Button(this);

        if (q%2 == 0) {
            myButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.klik_dwa));
        }
        else
             myButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.klik_jeden));

        final int number = new Random().nextInt(9);      
        final int rand = (ids[number]);
        myButton.setText(""+rand);
        myButton.setTypeface(type);
        myButton.setId(rand);
        myButton.setTag(rand);
        buttons[q][qq]=myButton;

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {



                 String mnozenie =" x ";
                 dzialanie.append(v.getTag().toString()+mnozenie);
                 int buttonValue = (int)v.getTag();
                 total *= buttonValue;
                 score.setText(String.valueOf(total));

                 myButton.findViewWithTag(v.getTag());
                 if(v.getId()==1)
                 {
                     counter*=1;
                 }

                 if(v.isClickable()){

                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                 for (int i=1;i<buttons.length;i++) {
                     for (int j=1;j<buttons[i].length;j++) {

                     }
                 }

                 String score1 = score.getText().toString();
                 int a;
                 a = Integer.parseInt(score1);
                 String tylemabyc1 = tylemabyc.getText().toString();
                 int b;
                 b = Integer.parseInt(tylemabyc1);

                 if(counter2>3){
                     counter2=0;
                     total = 1;
                     score.setText(null);
                     dzialanie.setText(null);
                     oklubnie.setText("Tylko trzy liczby mozęsz użyć");

                     for (int i=1;i<buttons.length;i++) {
                         for (int j=1;j<buttons[i].length;j++) {
                             Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                          if (btn.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                              btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                          }
                         }
                     }

                     new CountDownTimer(500, 100) {


                         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                         }


                        public void onFinish() {
                            oklubnie.setText("");
                         }
                        }.start();

                 }

                 if(a>b)
                 {
                     counter2=0;
                     total = 1;
                     score.setText(null);
                     counter-=5;
                     wynik.setText(""+counter);
                     dzialanie.setText(null);

                            wynik.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            wynikk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zle_bez_napisu);


                     for (int i=1;i<buttons.length;i++) {
                         for (int j=1;j<buttons[i].length;j++) {
                             Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                          if (btn.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                              btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                          }
                        }
                        }
                     new CountDownTimer(500, 100) {


                         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                         }

                        public void onFinish() {
                             wynikk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.czas_punkty_bez_napisu);
                             wynik.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         }
                        }.start();
                 }

                 new CountDownTimer(500, 100) {

                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                     }

                    public void onFinish() {

                          if(counter2<=3 &((String) score.getText()).equalsIgnoreCase((String) tylemabyc.getText()))
                            {
                                counter2=0;

                                wynik.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                wynikk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dobrze_bez_napisu);

                                 new CountDownTimer(500, 100) {


                                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                                     }

                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        wynikk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.czas_punkty_bez_napisu);
                                        wynik.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                     }
                                    }.start();

                                     for (int i=1;i<buttons.length;i++) {
                                         for (int j=1;j<buttons[i].length;j++) {
                                             Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                                          if (btn.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                                              btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                              btn.setTypeface(type);
                                                int number = new Random().nextInt(9);      
                                                int rand = (ids[number]);
                                                btn.setText(""+rand);

                                                btn.setId(rand);
                                                btn.setTag(rand);
                                                btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                                btn.setTextSize(25);

                                                if (i%2 == 0) {
                                                    btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.klik_dwa));
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.klik_jeden));

                                         }
                                        }
                                        }
                                     String razy= dzialanie.getText().toString();

                                        if(razy.length()>4)
                                            counter+=20;
                                        else if(razy.length()>3)
                                             counter+=10;
                                        else
                                             counter+=5;
                                dzialanie.setText(null);
                                score.setText(null);
                                Random rand = new Random();
                                int tablica[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,24,27,28,30,32,35,36,40,42,45,48,49,54,56,63,64,63,72,81};
                                int i = tablica[rand.nextInt(36)];

                                tylemabyc.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                                total = 1;
                                wynik.setText(""+counter);
                            }
                     }
                    }.start();

            }
        });

        tableRow.addView(myButton);
    }   
    }
   }
```

Comment: You description is hard to understand.

Comment: I have read this twice, but it's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Can you show us your code?  What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: sorry for weeak english. wait 2 mins i wil paste the code.

Comment: 63 is listed twice in the `results` array.

Comment: sometimes I draw numbers to my matrix from which I can't do  multiplication result.

Comment: Please show what the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/2zrnbqs.jpg   like here